# Web scraping python, can't call certain tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, vpn

I'm trying to access links to pdf files through a scraping script. (My ultimate goal is to download the PDFs, however, I'm learning as it goes and getting the links seemed like a good step in the workflow) The access to these files is restricted, but I have access via VPN. The option to download the pdf is available in my browser but when the script loops through the pages without returning any links to the pdf. Other data, like document titles, I can get and they show just fine. So I assume I had the way tags work figured out. Is this a problem specific to requesting links to PDFs or to using VPN to access? I will share script as well as the HTML from the site as you won't be able to get the latter without VPN access.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def elibrary_spider(max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
    if page < 2:
        url = \
            'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/browse?freeFilter=false&fromDate=1986&pageSize=100&sort=date&t_8=urn%3Aeng&toDate=2000&type_0=booksandjournals&redirect=true'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for first in soup.find_all('div', class_='s-pt-2'):
            for second in first('div', class_= 'contentItem nlm-book hasAccess hasCover standardResult chunkResult hi-visible s-px-4 s-py-3 s-bdr-b l-flex l-flex-row'):
                for titlelist in second('div', class_='downloadLinksModule closed'):
                    for ullink in titlelist('ul', class_='types'):
                        for link in ullink('li', class_='pdf'):
                            for pdf in link('a'):
                                href = 'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/' + pdf.get('href')
                                print(href)
        page += 1
        print(page)
        #Subsequent pages have differend url
    if page > 1:
        url = \
            'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/browse?freeFilter=false&fromDate=1986&page=' + str(page) \
            + '&pageSize=100&sort=date&t_8=urn%3Aeng&toDate=2000&type_0=booksandjournals'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for first in soup.find_all('div', class_='s-pt-2'):
            for second in first('div', class_= 'contentItem nlm-book hasAccess hasCover standardResult chunkResult hi-visible s-px-4 s-py-3 s-bdr-b l-flex l-flex-row'):
                for titlelist in second('div', class_='downloadLinksModule closed'):
                    for ullink in titlelist('ul', class_='types'):
                        for link in ullink('li', class_='pdf'):
                            for pdf in link('a'):
                                href = 'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/' + pdf.get('href')
                                print(href)
        page += 1
        print(page)
  elibrary_spider(3)
```

## -Edit-

And the HTML of the website is

[HTML Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBpw6.png)

This one actually works, it leads to the next pages. So the entry soup.find_all('div', class_='s-pt-2'): should be correct, right? (For this one no VPN is needed)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


#Crawl defined 'browse' page
def elibrary_spider(max_pages):
page = 1
while page <= max_pages:
    if page < 2:
        url = \
            'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/browse?freeFilter=false&fromDate=1986&pageSize=100&sort=date&t_8=urn%3Aeng&toDate=2000&type_0=booksandjournals&redirect=true'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for doclist in soup.find_all('div', class_='s-pt-2'):
            for titlelist in doclist('h2', class_= 'itemTitle'):
                for link in titlelist('a'):
                    href = 'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/' + link.get('href')
                    print(href)
                    get_publication(href)
        page += 1
        print(page)
        #Subsequent pages have differend url
    if page > 1:
        url = \
            'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/browse?freeFilter=false&fromDate=1986&page=' + str(page) \
            + '&pageSize=100&sort=date&t_8=urn%3Aeng&toDate=2000&type_0=booksandjournals'
        source_code = requests.get(url)
        plain_text = source_code.text
        soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, "html.parser")
        for doclist in soup.find_all('div', class_='s-pt-2'):
            for titlelist in doclist('h2', class_='itemTitle'):
                for link in titlelist('a'):
                    href = 'http://www.elibrary.imf.org/' + link.get('href')
                    print(href)
                    get_publication(href)
        page += 1
        print(page)

elibrary_spider(3)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `for first in soup.find_all('div', class_='s-pt-2')` I don't see any `<div class="s-pt-2">` elements in the html you posted.

Comment: I'm sorry, the <div class="s-pt-2" id="searchContent"> is the parent item and it fell away in pasting. This the base url.http://www.elibrary.imf.org/browse?freeFilter=false&fromDate=1986&page=1&pageSize=100&sort=date&t_8=urn%3Aeng&toDate=2000&type_0=booksandjournals&redirect=true

Comment: `for second in first('div', class_= 'contentItem nlm-book hasAccess hasCover standardResult chunkResult hi-visible s-px-4 s-py-3 s-bdr-b l-flex l-flex-row'):` Can first be used that way, just calling it directly like that?  You don't have to call `soup.find_all(...)`?

Comment: And again, I don't see any `<div class="contentItem nlm-book hasAccess hasCover standardResult chunkResult hi-visible s-px-4 s-py-3 s-bdr-b l-flex l-flex-row">` elements in that html.

Comment: As I understood the find_all searches for defined instances in the HTML, this is then saved in "first" to navigate within in tree I define what "second" is and search that within "one". https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-using-tag-names.

Comment: I will post a picture of the HTML tree of the website, that might be clearer.